# Pokemon FireRed - Magikarp refuses to evolve

Tags: pokemmo

I'm playing pokemon fire-red (PokeMMO actually) and my Magikarp reached level 20.
In all wiki sites it is mentioned that it will automatically evolve, but it (she) didn't.

What should I do?

Comment: What is PokeMMO ? Magikarp evolves at 20. If you're not playing one of the official pokemon games, it's entirely possible that they have failed to duplicate something correctly.

Comment: PokeMMO uses pirated ROMs for their asset base.  In that case, there's no way this game is even slightly legal.  Voting to close.

Comment: This question isn't asking anything illegal, isn't facilitating any illegal activities, and is asking an ostensibly answerable question  about an in-game mechanic. This is totally on-topic

Comment: @MarkTrapp The FAQ does specifically prohibit questions about "support with pirated games". I don't see how this does *not* fall in that categoty.

Comment: @Kareen It's not a pirated game. The game relies on the assets from a commercial game that we have no reason to believe the asker *doesn't* own. It's no different than mods, total conversion or otherwise, that rely on the original game assets and engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magikarp should evolve at level 20. Possible reasons why yours didn't:

- It's holding an Everstone
- You pressed B accidentally and stopped its evolution
- There's a bug in PokeMMO

Try taking the item from it (does PokeMMO have items?) and levelling it up again. If that fails, report it as a bug on the PokeMMO forums.

Comment: It's holding nothing, I'll try and leveling it up again.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common glitch with pokemmo. Three ways to fix it.

1. Log out and back in and level it up again. If that doesn't work try 2.
2. Trade it to a trusted friend and have them level it up once. If that doesn't work try 3.
3. Catch a new Magikarp and level it up.